# Is there a better way to get a single piece of data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

say i have some pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{ 'a': 123, 'b': 'something' }, { 'a': '345', 'b': 'else' }])
```

and i want to use the value `a` where `b == 'else'`

```
z = df[df['b'] == 'else'].reset_index().loc[0, 'a']
```

that just seems so cumbersome to get the single value (and not one record of a Series)  is there a better way to do this?  I find myself writing this bit of code a LOT, and it just seems wrong.

thanks!

Comment: `df.a[df.b=='else']`

Comment: or `df[df['b'] == 'else']['a'].tolist()`

Comment: why use `reset_index()` ?

Comment: df.a[df.b=='else'] returns a series, i want the int value of 123

Comment: df[df['b'] == 'else']['a'].tolist() obvi returns a list not a single int with a value of 123

Comment: i use reset index, because the conditional statement ensures (in my code) that i only get one row back.  but since i dont know which row it is in the index, i cant use the .loc function, so by resetting the index, i know my single row has index=0, and thus can use .loc[0, 'b']

Comment: df[df['b']=='else']['a'].values[0]